# How to return a value when a cell matches something without a certain set of characters? Using regexmatch

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm using IFS and REGEXMATCH to assign values to each cell. The desired outcome is to return 'Info' if a **cell contains** 'how' 'where' 'what' 'who' but at the same time **does not contain** 'buy' 'coupon' 'discount' and 'deals'. If the cell contains 'buy' 'coupon' 'discount' and 'deals', it should return 'Commercial'.

For example: cell containing 'where to go' should be Info,
cell containing 'how to buy' should be 'Commercial' because of the 'buy' keyword

My current formula looks like this:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(J9,"**how|where|what|who**<>buy<>coupon<>discount<>deals"),"Info",REGEXMATCH(J9,"buy|coupon|discount|deals"),"Commercial")
```

The problem here is it is returning 'Info' for cells like 'how to buy' when it should return 'Commercial'. It only works for 'who', but not for 'how' 'where' and 'what'.

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

I'm still new to regex, would appreciate it if anyone could help me fix this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula instead

```
=IF(AND(REGEXMATCH(J8,"how|where|what|who"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(J8,"buy|coupon|discount|deals"))),"Info","Commercial")
```

You cannot use `<>` in a regex. We use the `NOT` instead.

Functions used:

- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)
- [`NOT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305)